# How to view html character & in jsp input field?

Tags: mysql, jsp

How can i try to view html character `&` in my jsp textbox editDescription field and i don't want to show `&amp;` .

Here is my code >>>

```
function Edit(click) 
{
    var description= tablerow.cells[5].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("editDescription").value = description;
}
```

When i click the Edit button on the datatable, the Edit pop up will appear and binding the value like this.
`one month &amp; half day` instead of `one month & half day`.

Comment: When u retrieved the description from database, what is the result ? is it `"one month &amp ; half "` or `"one month & half"`

Comment: i tried to do the same and it works fine for me, input text field shows `&` instead of `&amp;`

Comment: i am using "select description from my employee table ".It show description as "one month & half " ...but In my JSP page it show "one month &amp ; half " .I don't know why ??

Comment: Hi, perhaps you can edit your question with code? to show what you have done so far..

Comment: ok ,now i edited my question with code .help me pls. i think it need to encode amp; before binding the editDescription field .i try with javascript encode method but it not work again .

Comment: where is your sql statement? what is the variable to store the data that retrieved from database? i dont see any data displayed in your textbox ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now i am ok with JavaScript replace method .
{document.getElementById("editDescription").value = description.replace(/&/g, '&'); }